# How can I insert multiple ranges of sequential numbers to 1 column in SQL?

Tags: sql, autofill, sequential

I have created an empty column "ZipCodes" in a table.
I want to autofill this column with the following numbers:
1000-3900
4000-9999

So all of these sequential numbers need to be in 1 column starting with 1000 and ending with 9999 but I don't want to include the range 3901-3999.
How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: Write a stored procedure.

Comment: Which database are you using

Comment: @jarlh so you mean I need to autofill from 1000 until 9999 and then write a procedure for using specifiek ranges? If yes, could you please tell me how to autofill then the column with numbers of 1000-9999?

Comment: @George I use Microsoft SQL

Comment: @FustratedDeveloper it is a newly created empty column. The way how Joseph has solved this works perfectly for me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with using CTE

```
;WITH temp_recoreds AS
(
SELECT 1000 AS ZipCode
UNION ALL
SELECT  CASE WHEN ZipCode=3900 THEN 4000 ELSE ZipCode+1 END AS ZipCode FROM temp_recoreds WHERE ZipCode<=9998
)
INSERT
      INTO Your_table(ZipCode)
      SELECT  z.ZipCode
      FROM temp_recoreds AS z
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this. This will generate numbers from 1000 till 10000 ignoring the numbers between 3901 and 4000.

```
with row_generator
  as (
         select *
           from master..spt_values
      )
  ,ten_thousand_rows
   as (
        select top 10000
               row_number() over(order by (select null))+1000 as rnk
          from row_generator a   
          join row_generator b
            on 1=1
        )
select rnk
  from ten_thousand_rows
where rnk between 1000 and 10000
  and NOT(rnk between 3901 and 3999)
```

After this you can do an

```
 with row_generator
      as (
             select *
               from master..spt_values
          )
      ,ten_thousand_rows
       as (
            select top 10000
                   row_number() over(order by (select null))+1000 as rnk
              from row_generator a   
              join row_generator b
                on 1=1
            )
    insert
      into dest_table(autofill_column)
    select rnk
      from ten_thousand_rows
    where rnk between 1000 and 10000
      and NOT(rnk between 3901 and 3999)
```